# Symbols in email headlines for pear mail

Tags: php, email, utf-8, smtp, pear

I'm trying to put a heart symbol ♥ into the headline of an email which should be sent via the php pear mail package.

But the receiver gets a ? instead of the heart so there has to be some mistake. It works if I manually send the email with my mail client.

My code is the following:

```
require_once "Mail.php";  
 $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
              array ('host' => 'host',
                         'port' => port,
                         'auth' => true,
                         'username' => 'username',
                         'password' => 'password');

$headers = array ('From' => 'sender',
          'Subject' => '♥ test',
          'Charset' => 'utf-8',

        );



$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, 'heart test');
```

What do I need to change in order to make the heart display correctly for the receiver of the email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not specifying the character set properly, so yes... it is a charset mismatch:

```
$headers = array(
   'Content-type' => 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'
);
```

is what you should have. There is no `Charset` header.

Comment: changed it to your suggestion but this heart still shows as ?. However if I put `=?UTF-8?B?4pml?=` instead of the heart symbol, the heart appears. What's up with that?

Comment: @Matthias You've properly encoded non-7-bit-safe characters for display in the subject is what's up with that.